# Give new item when button clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make the button on this page to print another random item. I created the function and when I click the button a new object appears in the console; however it doesn't print on the page.

```
import React from "react";
import './Random.css'

class Random extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      breweries: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          breweries: data,
        })
      })
  }

  reloadPage() {
    const brewery = this.state.breweries[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.state.breweries.length)];
    console.log(brewery)
  }

  render() {
    const brewery = this.state.breweries[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.state.breweries.length)];
    console.log(brewery)
    return(
    <div className="main">
      <div className="details">
          <p><b>Name:</b> {brewery && brewery.name}</p>
          <p className="category"><b>Category:</b> {brewery && brewery.brewery_type}</p>
          <p><b>Address:</b> {brewery && brewery && brewery.street}, {brewery && brewery.city},
      {brewery && brewery.state}, {brewery && brewery.postal_code}, {brewery && brewery.country}</p>
          <p><b>Phone Number:</b> {brewery && brewery.phone}</p>
          <p><b>Website:</b> <a href={brewery && brewery.website_url} target="_blank">{brewery && brewery.website_url}</a></p>
      </div>
      <div className="button">
        <button onClick={() => this.reloadPage()}>Get another random item</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Random;
```

Comment: I think you have taken brewery as const , it should be another type to reflect with the changes.

Comment: React document says: `By default, when your component’s state or props change, your component will re-render`.
You are not changing your component prop or state.

Comment: @ChinnaM You mean that because it is a const it won't change, so I should you use let instead?

Comment: @sadrzadehsina How can I make it change then?

Comment: @razvanusc I think the answer below is the point, follow it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `this.setState()`

```
reloadPage() {
    const brewery = this.state.breweries[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.state.breweries.length)];
    console.log(brewery)
this.setState({breweries:brewery})
  }
```

but in render you will again it randomized

So better

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.reloadPage()
      })
  }

  reloadPage() {
    const brewery = this.state.breweries[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.state.breweries.length)];
 this.setState({breweries:brewery})
  }

  render() {
    const brewery = this.state.breweries.length > 1 && this.state.breweries[0];
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work and I think it's because in this case you're setting the whole array of breweries to only one brewery

Comment: I fixed it by initialising brewery in the constructor and setting brewery:brewery

Comment: it will work because this.state.breweries[0], you randomize your array end every time you use 0 element